# How to display text on product catalog

Tags: text

I am currently looking to add text above my products, based on what category is selected.

How it currently looks

[image]

When headphones category is selected, some texts should appear

[image]

Comment: What theme? Main theme, or child, is it custom?

Comment: is the text coming from categories or custom fields? please explain here so can help you.

Comment: @TanmayPatel  I am using Flatsome theme. The text is custom text describing the category.  When Headphones is selected, I wanted a small blurb describing headphones,  when it's another category, I'd my custom blurb to display based on the category.